# How to get the usage metrics(count of views)

Tags: powerbi

How to get the usage metrics(count of views) of different dashboards at a time and populate the same in a report.
 I have more no. of dashboards and for each dashboard I can't go and click on usage metrics and see the count.
Is there anyway to do it dynamically .

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in Power BI dataset named **Dashboard Usage Metrics Model**. There is also **Report Usage Metrics Model** dataset. Both datasets keep the usage information up to 90 days for dashboards/reports stored in the workspace. Every workspace has its own datasets and they are created the first time when you open usage metric report in Power BI services for any report or dashboard.

To access the dataset choose Power BI dataset as the data source:
[image]
And then search for **Dashboard Usage Metrics Model** on you dataset list:
[image]